# How to Create a custom objectID in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, objectid

As far as i know, you can call ObjectId("something"); to generate a new id.

Is it possible to generate a random id, which does not already exist in the database/collection and has a specific format?

In my case, i want object id to generate a unique random 10digit number.

So the result should be:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID
var id = new ObjectId("something");
console.log(id) ==> 0123456789
```

Comment: In general this is not a good idea. ID collisions are very bad and you don't want one to happen. MongoDB ensures this won't happen, with a very low failure rate. But if you _insist_ on doing this, could you explain why you want to? An option would be to use `Date.now()` and use only the first 10 digits, but again I don't recommend it.

Comment: @Jason Fry So, if i get this correctly, ObjectId  does not check if an id already exists?

Comment: @Jason Fry The idea is that every dataset in the database has an unique 10digit id, which will exist and not change, as long as the data exists. So the idea was to use the ganerated id as this id.

Comment: If you're just creating a new `ObjectId`, I'm pretty sure it _doesn't_ check because it wouldn't know where to check. And it doesn't sound like you need to generate a 10-digit ID instead of what MongoDB generates. MongoDB ObjectIds do not change, and exist as long as the data exists. Whenever you create a new document in the database it will automatically generate an ObjectId for that new document.

Answer (score 2):

As in the comments, your best bet would be to get seconds into the current year when inserting the document. But the real question would be how intensive would insertion of new documents be. You need to account for multiple factors, first being the more documents you insert, the higher the chance your ids will collide at one point.

I would recommend just leaving the standard GUID mongo generates for you, however a solution that I can think of from top of my head would be getting the seconds into the current year, substring that to get the last 5 digits, and then generate 5 random digits and merge them together.

```
new Date().getTime().toString().substring(8) + Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999 - 10000)) + 100000;
```

With the above (80 bits) you would get `4.135898×10-13` collision probability on 1000000 documents.

Comment: I see now that using objectID might be a bad idea. I'll try the date approach. -thx